# Power BI DAX | Multiple Slicers from Different DIM TABLES with Multiple ALLSELECTED DAX statements

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to to write ALLSELECTED DAX with multiple slicer values where slicers come from different Dim Tables?

Goal: A Table in Power BI where end users can select the external slicers filtering a table and see the sum cost based upon the 3 above mentioned external slicers. See picture below.

Example:

Slicer 1 has Project Name (DimProject[ProjectName])

Slicer 2 has Project Manager (DimTeam[ProjectManager])

Slicer 3 has Calendar Year & Month (DimDate[CalendarYearAndMonth])

I tried the following: CACULATE(SUM(COST), ALLSELECTED(DimProject[ProjectName]), ALLSELECTED(DimTeam[ProjectManager]), ALLSELECTED(DimDate[CalendarYearAndMonth]) )

It didn't work. Can anyone advise on what is the correct way to filter with multiple slicer values [from different tables] while using ALLSELECTED? Is there a better pattern I should be using?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? what result do you expect?

Comment: Hey. I edited the original post. Goal: A Table in Power BI where end users can select the external slicers filtering a table and see the sum cost based upon the 3 above mentioned external slicers. See picture in post.

Comment: That sounds like the normal behavior of PowerBI, having proper relationships between the fact table and the 3 dimensions should suffice. then you just need a simple SUM('Table'[Column])

Comment: Appreciate the response. The issue though is that all the columns, whether I use 1 ALLSELECTED statement, or none turn out to be exactly the same number, whether I use a Table, a Matrix.

Comment: in what kind of a scenario would a person use 3 ALLSELECTED statements like above?

Comment: The only scenario I can think of is to calculate a grand total (filtered by the specified tables/columns). If the value is always the same maybe there is a problem in the relationships in your model. can you provide a schema of that?

Comment: I'll try. I have to change all the data - it'll take so long!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `TREATAS` function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/treatas-function